# Still can't understand python import

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Sorry for stupid question. I have these files:

```
a\
|-__init__.py
|-b\
|---__init__.py
|---c.py
```

c.py contains class 'd'.

This form works:

```
>>> import a.b.c as c

>>> from a import b
```

These forms don't work:

```
>>> from a.b import c
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'c'
cannot import name 'c'

>>> from a.b.c import d
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'a.b.c'
No module named 'a.b.c'
```

1. If `from a import b` works, why does `from a.b import c` throw an error?
2. If `import a.b.c` works, why does `from a.b import c` throw an error?
3. If `'d' from 'c'` works, why does `from a.b.c import d` throw an error?

Comment: All your "broken" examples work on my Python 2.7 and 3.4 systems.

Comment: I concur with what John said, but just to check: are you consistently running from the root of your project (meaning a is subdirectory of the working directory, versus running from inside a)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for time wasting.

I experimented with the import and edited `__init__.py`. Deleting `.pyc` cache solve the problem.